# Iterate thorought multi-dimensional json

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I am working on C# project, I came up with a scenario where I am returning a 
 JSON object with a dataset of 2 data-tables(Table and Table1).

How to Iterate data so that data can be copied in 2 different variable.

**Ajax Call:-**

```
 $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '@Url.Action("DrawChart")',
            data: '{}',
            success: function (chartsdataSet) {             
                var chartsdata = chartsdataSet.Table[0];
     }
    });
```

**JSON Object:-**

```
 {
      "Table": [
        {
          "PlanName": "Half Yearly",
          "Paymentamount": 17925,
          "SettledAmount": 13300,
          "PackageAmount": 12479
        },
        {
          "PlanName": "Quaretly",
          "Paymentamount": 7900,
          "SettledAmount": 6000,
          "PackageAmount": 8000
        },
        {
          "PlanName": "Yearly",
          "Paymentamount": 8200,
          "SettledAmount": 9000,
          "PackageAmount": 5198
        }
      ],
      "Table1": [
        {
          "year": 2017,
          "monthid": 1,
          "MonthName": "Jan",
          "Paymentamount": 7900,
          "SettledAmount": 6000,
          "PackageAmount": 8000
        },
        {
          "year": 2017,
          "monthid": 2,
          "MonthName": "Feb",
          "Paymentamount": 1500,
          "SettledAmount": 1300,
          "PackageAmount": 1900
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: *can be copied in 2 variables* - What do you mean ? `var a = chartsdataSet.Table, b = chartsdataSet.Table1;` ?

Comment: yeah tables in 2 different variables as you specified, its returning undefined in a and b..

Comment: Is the described JSON what you find in `chartsdataSet` ?

Comment: the same json object which I showed above..

Comment: What is the output of `chartsdataSet["Table"]` ?

Comment: undefined again

Comment: Then your problem is there. You do not receive data. Check your url and check the error you get

Comment: I pasted the output of chartsdataSet above in json

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse(chartsdataSet)` ?

Comment: thanks, yes,JSON.parse(chartsdataSet) did the trick, I have tried JSON.stringify(chartsdataSet) as well but didn't work..

Comment: Cool, I posted an answer thus it is more visible and you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive JSON data. If you want to use it as a Javascript object you should use `JSON.parse(chartsdataSet)`

```
 $(function() {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         url: '@Url.Action("DrawChart")',
         data: '{}',
         success: function(chartsdataSet) {
             var object = JSON.parse(chartsdataSet);
             var chartsdata = object.Table[0];
         }
     });
 })
```